# Part of enlarged photo changes from original

Tags: portrait

I copied a photo from the net to my computer of a friend standing in front of a brick wall with a window in it.

On my computer I enlarged the photo slightly.

The original photo shows the lines that the bricks and window form, at a noticeable angle, from upper left to lower right.
The copy I made shows these lines perfectly horizontal.
Other than enlarged, the image of the person didn’t change, or its position relative to the bricks/window.

Why is this? (I do not want to post the photos)

Comment: _Exactly_ how did you "enlarge the photo slightly"? Which programs did you use, and precisely which tools?

Comment: Philip, you are way over my head here, sorry. I roll the mouse like I would with another photo to enlarge. All I can tell you is I have not seen changes other than the enlargement as expected in the past of other photos. This I did years ago on a different computer.
Thanks for your time.
Clay

Comment: OK, you don't want to post the photo. And you can't tell us what program, running on your computer, you used to "slightly" enlarge the image. A vague verbal description and an explanation that the problem arose when you "rolled your mouse"  is a question which cannot be answered with the information you provided.

Comment: It is clear I don't have the knowledge to answer your questions and without posting the pic, I can only say thanks again for your time.

Comment: It sounds to me like you haven't enlarged the photo, but rather you've just zoomed in. There's a distinction there. Anyway, since you seem to be relatively inexperienced in the area, I would suggest the best option here is to ask a tech-savvy friend/relative for the explanation. Get them standing next to you, and show them what you're doing.

Comment: That makes sense, osullic, I will and let you know their opinion. Thanks.